# Have to insert a row in a datagrid in top Position by clicking Another row and copy the items of that row

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, mvvm, wpf-controls

Have to insert a row in a Datagrid having checkbox column, in top Position of that Grid by clicking check box of another row and copy the items of  that particular row.

Comment: Have you tried anything..?

Comment: I can able to add row in zeroth position, but don't have any idea how to copy the row element to the new row. I Am using collection to add new row.
   tempCollection.Insert(0, new RowCollection());

Comment: I have created some temporary variable eg: name,age 
then name=tempcollection[i].Name
     age=tempCollection[i].Age
then pass it tempCollection.Insert(0, new RowCollection(){Name=name, Age=age})

Comment: You using biniding or just code behind and what type of collection is your TempCollection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

You need to get the DataGrid index on which u checked and want the data of that particular row   in first row.

```
class Details
{
public string Name{get;set;}
public string Age{get;set;}
}

ObservableCollection<Details> tempcollection{get;set;}

private void DataGrid_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGrid dg = sender as DataGrid;
            gridIndex = dg.SelectedIndex;
        }
```

Then you can try this:

I hope your tempCollection is the observable collection Bind to the DataGrid..If it is then,

```
tempCollection.Insert(0, new Details
{
Name=tempCollection[gridIndex].Name,
Age=tempCollection[gridIndex].Age
});
```